# TypeError: crypto.randomUUID is not a function

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js

My Next.js app works like a charm on `http://localhost:3000/`.

I added the following line to my `hosts` file.

```
127.0.0.1 whatever.local
```

When I connect to `http://whatever.local:3000/`, my **client-side** components return the following error.

**TypeError: crypto.randomUUID is not a function**

I use `crypto.randomUUID()` when creating child objects such as in the the following example.

```
{lookupItemList.map((lookupItem: LookupItem) =>
    <option
        key={crypto.randomUUID()}
        value={lookupItem.key}>
        {lookupItem.value}
    </option>
)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, it's not a good practice to use crypto.randomUUID() as key of your elements, instead use item id's or any other specific data on your items.

and for your question,Note that window.crypto.randomUUID is only available under HTTPS context.
localhost is treated a secure origin, even without HTTPS.
For everything apart from localhost, you do need HTTPS.

Comment: Thank you, Maziyar, for your explanation about HTTPS. 
As a matter of fact, it is boldly stated here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/randomUUID.
I can definitely use my keys. Could you please elaborate on why using crypto.randomUUID() for this purpose it is not a good practice?

Comment: sure,using random generated strings or even index of array for react element key has some significant cons.
for example, if you mutate the list( like delete or add something), it will re-render the whole list. only use uuid or index, when are certainly sure that this list wont change.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to `crypto.randomUUID()`, you may use the `uuid` library.

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
let uuid = uuidv4(); 
console.log(uuid) // ⇨ '9b1deb4d-3b7d-4bad-9bdd-2b0d7b3dcb6d'
```

so, for your code:

```
{lookupItemList.map((lookupItem: LookupItem) =>
    <option
        key={uuid}
        value={lookupItem.key}>
        {lookupItem.value}
    </option>
)}
```

Comment: you could, but as i told in the top answer, using random string or number as key in react is a bad practice and you should avoid it as much as you can.

Comment: obviously, you are right. I posted this answer assuming there is no such data as `id` or similar properties.